# Emulator networking ip address and virtual router

Tags: networking, android-emulator

I am using android emulator on windows. The android developer doc says that each instance of the emulator runs behind a virtual router/firewall service. The virtual router for each instance manages the 10.0.2/24 network address space . However, when I connect to the emulator with `adb shell` and do `ifconfig`, I got the following output:

> radio0    Link encap:UNSPEC
>             inet addr:192.168.200.2  Bcast:192.168.200.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>
> wlan0     Link encap:UNSPEC
>             inet addr:192.168.232.2  Bcast:192.168.239.255  Mask:255.255.248.0

`ip route show` gives me the following output

> 192.168.200.0/24 dev radio0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.200.2
>
> 192.168.232.0/21 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.232.2

I do not see any of the 10.2.x.x ip address. Where are those ip address?

Also does the virtual router run within the emulator (on the Android OS) or run on windows? How to exam the virtual router?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue running Android 7.1.1 (API 25) on Windows.
But when I emulating Android 7.0 (API 24) it works as expected. Device gets IP 10.0.2.15. In this case `ip route show` will bring 10.2.x.x address. So, if you can just use prior versions (API 16 - API 24).

This router exists inside emulator and Windows is not aware about it.
If you need to access service running inside emulator from Windows, you need to add port mappings:

```
telnet localhost 5554
auth <token from 'C:\Users\{user}\.emulator_console_auth_token'>
redir add tcp:8080:8080
```

Then you can access your service by: 127.0.0.1:8080. However, this approach does not work with Android 7.1.1. I have no ideas what is wrong with it.

Comment: Going to old version is lame. Checkout my answer, which I discovered yesterday.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that since API 25, the networking of an emulator has changed. The device IP is no longer 10.0.2.15, and issuing a 'redir' command via telnet, as it is documented, no longer work.

In order to have a redirection, use the adb program. First, make sure adb is in your earch path. Typically, it is under Android/Sdk/platform-tools, wherever the Android SDK is located, whatever OS you are using.

Then, use the following command line:

```
adb forward tcp:<host port> tcp:<guest port>
```

(For example: `adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080`). Now, you can access port  with: `telnet localhost <host port>`, which will be redirected to the guest.

This is very unfortunate, because (as of build 28) it isn't documented this way. I assume at some point documentation will be fixed.

Comment: I can confirm this works, it's been incredibly hard to find this answer, wish I could upvote more

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends. I've connected to and tested my [SFTP Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.becke.sftp_server__s0_v1) app on an "Android 11 API 30 Emulator" and on an "Android TV 9 API 28 Emulator".

On the "Android 11 API 30 Emulator" my SFTP Server app showed up listening on IP 10.0.2.16 and port 6789 and I could connect to it using `redir add tcp:<localhost-port>:6789` (further details see [Setting up redirection through the Emulator Console](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#redirection)). BUT I could as well connect to it using `adb -s <emulator-id> forward tcp:<localhost-port> tcp:6789`.

On the "Android TV 9 API 28 Emulator" my SFTP Server app showed up listening on IP 192.168.232.2 and port 6789 and I could ONLY connect to it using `adb -s <emulator-id> forward tcp:<localhost-port> tcp:6789`. I could NOT connect to it using `redir add tcp:<localhost-port>:6789`.

**Conclusion "adb forward" is always working and therefore should be used**. (Do not use "redir add tcp" that only sometimes works in the address range 10.0.2.0/24).