# How can I bypass the Android emulator virtual router and create a multi-emulator network without redirects?

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator

The [official documentation on Android emulator networking](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html) is quite basic, and doesn't help me solve my problem. In fact, it looks like it's outdated too, based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48522531/emulator-networking-ip-address-and-virtual-router).

I'm trying to create an scripted test setup which would build my .apk from source (already done), start two headless emulator instances with the .apk installed (needs some refining) and then run some network tests with the app. The problem is that the app itself is a low-level networking application, which I need to be tested in a non-NAT environment, but that's unavoidable with the emulator's built-in virtual router.

Are there any tricks to avoid that router, and get something like "bridged networking" instead of "NAT", like we have in VirtualBox for example?

I looked at the `ip rule` output inside the emulator, the content of the different routing tables, and the `iptables` rules, but couldn't find anything useful yet (see [examples from someone else](https://gist.github.com/ganadist/730f2085353b089290b6112d1802ac73)).